# How to list repos?

Tags: python, github, github-app

I'm using the following package in order to generate a github app:
https://github.com/swinton/github-app-demo.py

I was able to get the installation and all the details looks ok there. However, when I'm trying to list the repos, using the url:
*"installation/repositories"*,
I'm getting an empty set. Thought maybe it's a permissions issue so granted the app all the possible permissions but still no luck.

update:
when adding a new repo for my user I was able to see it. However, I can't see the organisation's repos.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Nir.

Comment: Can you post ur code please?

Comment: @DineshKumar- the code is in the link. 
https://github.com/swinton/github-app-demo.py
didn't change anything meaningful.

Comment: Could you check whether the organization's repositories are private. Also, is the authentication properly setup. As per https://developer.github.com/apps/building-github-apps/authenticating-with-github-apps/#authenticating-as-an-installation one needs to provide an installation access token and this token gets invalidated when repository permissions are changed. Also the installation tokens expire after sometime.

Comment: thanks @AsifKamranMalick. The issue was that I installed in my private area and not in the organization. Therefore, I wasn't able to see the organization's repos.

Comment: @Nir99 Glad it got resolved. It would be great you just post an answer and accept it. This will help others.

Comment: @AsifKamranMalick done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this was that I've installed the the app in my private area and not in the organization. Therefore, I wasn't able to access the organization's private repos.